# Transaction commit in HttpSessionListener not persisting to DB

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jta

I recently started using JBossTM in order to use JTA over multiple database connections, which was very successful. If I try to perform a transaction from any controller it works without any issues.

However, I recently started trying to persist entities from an instance of HttpSessionListener so I can track user sessions and I haven't been able to get the persist working. I'm sure there is something very simple I am missing here but any tips would be most welcome.

The problem is that although everything seems to run ok (logs wise) nothing actually gets committed to the database. I've seen the error before when trying to persist to a database with no transaction manager (before I switched to JBossTM) but can't seem to crack this.

Here are the relevant bits of my application-context.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager" factory-method="transactionManager" id="arjunaTransactionManager"/>
<bean class="com.arjuna.ats.jta.UserTransaction" factory-method="userTransaction" id="arjunaUserTransaction"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
  <property name="transactionManager">
    <ref bean="arjunaTransactionManager"/>
  </property>
  <property name="userTransaction">
    <ref bean="arjunaUserTransaction"/>
  </property>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="CoreDS" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/jdbc/CoreDS" resource-ref="true" />

<bean id="coreEMW" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="coreEMF"/>

<bean id="coreEMF" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="CoreDS"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionDAO" class="core.dao.SessionDAOImpl"
    p:entityManager-ref="coreEMW" />

<bean name="openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor"
      p:entityManagerFactory-ref="coreEMF" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

<bean id='jdbcTemplate' class='org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate'
    p:dataSource-ref='CoreDS' />
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>core.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

SessionListener.java

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SessionListener.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        getDAO(event).save(new Session(event.getSession().getId(),Calendar.getInstance()));
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        ....
    }   

    private SessionDAO getDAO(HttpSessionEvent event){
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();

        ApplicationContext ctx = 
            WebApplicationContextUtils.
                  getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

        SessionDAO dao = 
                      (SessionDAO) ctx.getBean("sessionDAO");

        return dao;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="...">
 <persistence-unit name="BPSCorePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
 <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/BPSCoreDS</non-jta-data-source>
 ...
 <class>core.model.Session</class>
 <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
 <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
 </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

logs (where the Session object is not persisted although you can see the commit)

```
2013-04-18 15:47:41,763 [core.util.SessionListener] TRACE - sessionCreated(): C5A37E5CC12FF19C277769DA8B97BF0A
2013-04-18 15:47:41,798 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - BaseTransaction.getStatus
2013-04-18 15:47:41,854 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Loading class com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.coordinator.CheckedActionFactoryImple
2013-04-18 15:47:41,873 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - BaseTransaction.begin
2013-04-18 15:47:41,882 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Loading class com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
2013-04-18 15:47:41,889 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Loading class com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowNoFileLockStore
2013-04-18 15:47:41,891 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.createHierarchy(/tmp/jbosstm/tx/a/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,900 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] INFO  - ARJUNA012163: Starting service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService on port 32882
2013-04-18 15:47:41,910 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Loading class com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.utils.SocketProcessId
2013-04-18 15:47:41,912 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] INFO  - ARJUNA012337: TransactionStatusManagerItem host: 127.0.0.1 port: 32882
2013-04-18 15:47:41,913 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - OutputObjectState::OutputObjectState()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,914 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Loading class com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.objectstore.ShadowNoFileLockStore
2013-04-18 15:47:41,914 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.createHierarchy(/tmp/jbosstm/tx/a/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,915 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.write_committed(0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:0, /Recovery/TransactionStatusManager)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,916 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ShadowingStore.write_state(0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:0, /Recovery/TransactionStatusManager, StateType.OS_ORIGINAL)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,916 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ShadowingStore.genPathName(0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:0, /Recovery/TransactionStatusManager, StateType.OS_ORIGINAL)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,916 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.genPathName(0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:0, /Recovery/TransactionStatusManager, 11)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,918 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.openAndLock(/tmp/jbosstm/tx/a/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/Recovery/TransactionStatusManager/0_ffffc0a80036_8073_5170078d_0, FileLock.F_WRLCK, true)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,918 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.createHierarchy(/tmp/jbosstm/tx/a/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/Recovery/TransactionStatusManager/0_ffffc0a80036_8073_5170078d_0)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,927 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - FileSystemStore.closeAndUnlock(/tmp/jbosstm/tx/a/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/Recovery/TransactionStatusManager/0_ffffc0a80036_8073_5170078d_0, null, java.io.FileOutputStream@283a0f10)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,927 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] INFO  - ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 32882 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
2013-04-18 15:47:41,928 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - StateManager::StateManager( 2, 0 )
2013-04-18 15:47:41,928 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::BasicAction()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,929 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::Begin() for action-id 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2
2013-04-18 15:47:41,929 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::actionInitialise() for action-id 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2
2013-04-18 15:47:41,930 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ActionHierarchy::ActionHierarchy(1)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,931 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ActionHierarchy::add(0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2, 1)
2013-04-18 15:47:41,934 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::addChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 adding Thread["ajp-bio-8010"-exec-1,5,main]
2013-04-18 15:47:41,935 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::addChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 adding Thread["ajp-bio-8010"-exec-1,5,main] result = true
2013-04-18 15:47:41,938 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::instantiate()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,939 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::TransactionReaper ( 9223372036854775807 )
2013-04-18 15:47:41,941 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ReaperThread.run ()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,942 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Thread Thread[Transaction Reaper,5,main] sleeping for 9223370670558313865
2013-04-18 15:47:41,942 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::insert ( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 60 )
2013-04-18 15:47:41,944 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ReaperElement::ReaperElement ( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 status: ActionStatus.RUNNING, 60 )
2013-04-18 15:47:41,944 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ReaperThread.run ()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,944 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::check ()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,944 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::check - comparing 1366296521944
2013-04-18 15:47:41,945 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Thread Thread[Transaction Reaper,5,main] sleeping for 59999
2013-04-18 15:47:41,946 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - ReaperWorkerThread.run ()
2013-04-18 15:47:41,946 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - Thread Thread[Transaction Reaper Worker 0,5,main] waiting for cancelled TXs
2013-04-18 15:47:42,091 [dao.BaseDAOImpl] TRACE - Persisting
2013-04-18 15:47:42,091 [dao.BaseDAOImpl] DEBUG - adtest Shared EntityManager proxy for target factory [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@1dcd8d1f]
2013-04-18 15:47:42,091 [dao.BaseDAOImpl] DEBUG - adtest core.model.Session@6229abca
2013-04-18 15:47:42,120 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - BaseTransaction.getStatus
2013-04-18 15:47:42,120 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - TransactionImple.getStatus
2013-04-18 15:47:42,121 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - BaseTransaction.getStatus
2013-04-18 15:47:42,121 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - TransactionImple.getStatus
2013-04-18 15:47:42,121 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - BaseTransaction.commit
2013-04-18 15:47:42,121 [com.arjuna.ats.jta] TRACE - TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate
2013-04-18 15:47:42,121 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::End() for action-id 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2
2013-04-18 15:47:42,122 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::removeChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 removing TSThread:1
2013-04-18 15:47:42,122 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - BasicAction::removeChildThread () action 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 removing TSThread:1 result = true
2013-04-18 15:47:42,122 [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] TRACE - TransactionReaper::remove ( BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a80036:8073:5170078d:2 status: ActionStatus.COMMITTED )
```

all edited to remove client detail, so there may be some mistakes

Any help is more gratefully appreciated!

Comment: Did u solve this issue? If yes please tell us the answer

Comment: I realise it's a while since I posted this but only just saw your comment, I took it out of the transaction manager and just went straight to the datasource and ran an update query that way.

Comment: Did you try with the `@Stateless` annotation? It's working with Eclipselink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone finding this now, I ended up going straight to the data source and running an insert query.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    log.trace("sessionCreated(): "+event.getSession().getId());

    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(getDS(event));
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String datetime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    select.update("INSERT INTO sessions (username, session, started) VALUES ('','"+event.getSession().getId()+"','"+datetime+"')");
}
private DataSource getDS(HttpSessionEvent event){
    HttpSession session = event.getSession();

    ApplicationContext ctx = 
        WebApplicationContextUtils.
              getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

    DataSource dao = 
                  (DataSource) ctx.getBean("BPSCoreDS");

    return dao;
}
```